# 'User' doesn't have enough reputation to chat -- wrong 'User' displayed by javascript

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat

After an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955136/wordpress-custom-post-types-problem/6955287#6955287) on Stack Overflow, I had an extended discussion with the OP, [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880397/dave), and was asked -- as expected --  to "move this to chat".  However, when I clicked on it, I got the message:

> ChrisCarson doesn't have enough reputation to talk in chat.

I, [Chris Carson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611486/chris-carson), have more than enough reputation to talk in chat, *though the other user [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880397/dave) didn't*.  I believe the message should have been the other way around -- "*Dave* doesn't have ...".  Here is what I saw:

[image: Here's a screenshot of the problem]

Comment: It's also weird that your user name is displayed WithoutAnySpaces. That's not how you've entered it on Stack Overflow, or how it's displayed in the comments.

Comment: Note, there is *not* another user with the name ChrisCarson on [so].  (Without the space as Cody noted)

Comment: @cody-gray Yes. I did update my profile yesterday to have the space. I don't think I've logged out since. I logged out to see if that fixed the problem.  It didn't.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, as far as chat is concerned - you didn't ;p It looks like the "migrate to chat" route doesn't do an automatic refresh, so you only had 16 rep as far as chat knew (it is a separate system that refreshes when you use it). I've refreshed it manually now, and for future use I've also made this automatic when migrating.

So;

- it was talking about the correct user
- but it was confused about the name
- the missing space is also explained by your comment "I did update my profile yesterday to have the space" - same thing; the user record hadn't been updated

Comment: My reputation precedes me not.  Cheers.  Thanks, Chris

Comment: @Chris - your reputation precedes you but doesn't follow you, I think is the issue :)